# PHP & Javascript Assignment Issue

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

I have the following situation:

In a codeignitor project, from the controller, I load a view.

Within that view, I load another view. This sub view is slide open and close based on a radio box selection.

Now this sub view expects the value of the radio box selected.

```
<?php $this->load->view('myview', $value); ?>
```

Since the main view is already loaded, and loads the sub view too, how can I assign the value of the radio box selected to the $value variable?

I am using this code for radio box:

```
<input type='radio' name='var1' id='var1' value='myvalue' onchange=show('true');>
```

Then in the SHOW function I have this:

```
function show(val) {
    if (val == 'true') {
        var var1 = $("#var1:checked").val();
    }
}
```

So I get the value on change to var1 in javascript correctly. But how to pass this value to the value variable in the sub view:

```
<?php $this->load->view('myview', $value); ?>
```

Tried the AJAX route too:

I tried ajax route and did this: 
    $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "",
                data: "var1=" + value,
                success: function(result) {
                }
            });

And in controller funtion set the

```
$this->template->set('$value', $this->input->post('var1'));
echo 1;
```

But still the

```
<?php $this->load->view('myview', $value); ?>
```

doesn't read value.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
 $this->data['value']= $value;
 $this->load->view('myview',$this->data['value']);
?>
```

myview.php

```
<?php
   echo $value;    
?>
```

Comment: How would this work? This is not referencing the selected readio button value?

Comment: you pass the array ('value'=>$value) to the view and codeignitor  will  make it as $value

Answer (score 0):

There are two environments that you are working on. What you can do is to send a GET or POST variable to your PHP script and process the data. Because everything is rendered in the back-end (PHP part) you need to get status of the checkbox before to load your views. So, without ajax your option is to reload the page with a get parameter set.

Comment: Added ajax test in my post.